# PHP install fails on Ubuntu 14 (make: *** [sapi/cli/php] Error 1) PHP 5.6.20

Tags: php, compilation

I am using the following configuration:

```
./configure --with-libdir=lib --with-config-file-path=/etc/ --with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php5/mods-available --with-pear --enable-cli --enable-intl --with-icu-dir=/opt/icu4c --enable-bcmath --disable-cgi --enable-fpm --with-zlib --with-openssl --with-kerberos --with-bz2 --with-curl --enable-ftp --enable-zip --enable-exif --with-gd --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib64 --with-freetype-dir=/usr/lib64 --enable-gd-native-ttf --with-gettext --with-gmp --with-mhash --with-iconv --with-imap --with-mysql --with-imap-ssl --enable-sockets --enable-soap --with-xmlrpc --with-mcrypt --enable-mbstring --enable-embedded-mysqli --with-mysqli=mysqlnd --with-mysql-sock --with-sqlite3 --with-pdo-mysql --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd --with-pdo-sqlite --enable-phar --enable-pcntl
```

and the make fails after sometime giving the following error:

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sapi/cli/php] Error 1
```

I searched and most docs tell about using a make clean, which did not help and ‘-lresolve’ is already in my Makefile

Following is what happens just before error:

```
/tmp/kitchen/cache/php-5.6.20/ext/intl/breakiterator/codepointiterator_internal.cpp:279: undefined reference to `utext_getNativeIndex_55'
/tmp/kitchen/cache/php-5.6.20/ext/intl/breakiterator/codepointiterator_internal.cpp:280: undefined reference to `utext_clone_55'
/tmp/kitchen/cache/php-5.6.20/ext/intl/breakiterator/codepointiterator_internal.cpp:285: undefined reference to `utext_setNativeIndex_55'
/tmp/kitchen/cache/php-5.6.20/ext/intl/breakiterator/codepointiterator_internal.cpp:286: undefined reference to `utext_getNativeIndex_55'
ext/intl/breakiterator/.libs/codepointiterator_internal.o: In function `PHP::CodePointBreakIterator::setText(UText*, UErrorCode&)':
/tmp/kitchen/cache/php-5.6.20/ext/intl/breakiterator/codepointiterator_internal.cpp:128: undefined reference to `utext_clone_55'
ext/intl/breakiterator/.libs/codepointiterator_internal.o: In function `PHP::CodePointBreakIterator::operator==(icu_55::BreakIterator const&) const':
/tmp/kitchen/cache/php-5.6.20/ext/intl/breakiterator/codepointiterator_internal.cpp:84: undefined reference to `utext_equals_55'
ext/intl/breakiterator/.libs/codepointiterator_internal.o: In function `PHP::CodePointBreakIterator::CodePointBreakIterator()':
/tmp/kitchen/cache/php-5.6.20/ext/intl/breakiterator/codepointiterator_internal.cpp:37: undefined reference to `icu_55::BreakIterator::BreakIterator()'
/tmp/kitchen/cache/php-5.6.20/ext/intl/breakiterator/codepointiterator_internal.cpp:40: undefined reference to `utext_openUChars_55'
/tmp/kitchen/cache/php-5.6.20/ext/intl/breakiterator/codepointiterator_internal.cpp:37: undefined reference to `icu_55::BreakIterator::~BreakIterator()'
ext/intl/breakiterator/.libs/codepointiterator_internal.o: In function `PHP::CodePointBreakIterator::operator=(PHP::CodePointBreakIterator const&)':
/tmp/kitchen/cache/php-5.6.20/ext/intl/breakiterator/codepointiterator_internal.cpp:58: undefined reference to `utext_clone_55'
ext/intl/breakiterator/.libs/codepointiterator_internal.o: In function `PHP::CodePointBreakIterator::CodePointBreakIterator(PHP::CodePointBreakIterator const&)':
/tmp/kitchen/cache/php-5.6.20/ext/intl/breakiterator/codepointiterator_internal.cpp:44: undefined reference to `icu_55::BreakIterator::~BreakIterator()'
ext/intl/breakiterator/.libs/codepointiterator_internal.o: In function `PHP::CodePointBreakIterator::clone() const':
/tmp/kitchen/cache/php-5.6.20/ext/intl/breakiterator/codepointiterator_internal.cpp:93: undefined reference to `icu_55::UMemory::operator new(unsigned long)'
/tmp/kitchen/cache/php-5.6.20/ext/intl/breakiterator/codepointiterator_internal.cpp:93: undefined reference to `icu_55::UMemory::operator delete(void*)'
ext/intl/breakiterator/.libs/codepointiterator_internal.o: In function `PHP::CodePointBreakIterator::createBufferClone(void*, int&, UErrorCode&)':
/tmp/kitchen/cache/php-5.6.20/ext/intl/breakiterator/codepointiterator_internal.cpp:255: undefined reference to `icu_55::UMemory::operator new(unsigned long)'
/tmp/kitchen/cache/php-5.6.20/ext/intl/breakiterator/codepointiterator_internal.cpp:255: undefined reference to `icu_55::UMemory::operator delete(void*)'
ext/intl/breakiterator/.libs/codepointiterator_internal.o: In function `PHP::CodePointBreakIterator::getUText(UText*, UErrorCode&) const':
/tmp/kitchen/cache/php-5.6.20/ext/intl/breakiterator/codepointiterator_internal.cpp:109: undefined reference to `utext_clone_55'
ext/intl/breakiterator/.libs/codepointiterator_internal.o: In function `PHP::CodePointBreakIterator::~CodePointBreakIterator()':
/tmp/kitchen/cache/php-5.6.20/ext/intl/breakiterator/codepointiterator_internal.cpp:67: undefined reference to `icu_55::BreakIterator::~BreakIterator()'
ext/intl/breakiterator/.libs/codepointiterator_internal.o: In function `PHP::CodePointBreakIterator::~CodePointBreakIterator()':
/tmp/kitchen/cache/php-5.6.20/ext/intl/breakiterator/codepointiterator_internal.cpp:73: undefined reference to `icu_55::UMemory::operator delete(void*)'
ext/intl/breakiterator/.libs/codepointiterator_internal.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN3PHP22CodePointBreakIteratorE[_ZTIN3PHP22CodePointBreakIteratorE]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for icu_55::BreakIterator'
ext/intl/breakiterator/.libs/codepointiterator_internal.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3PHP22CodePointBreakIteratorE[_ZTVN3PHP22CodePointBreakIteratorE]+0xa8): undefined reference to `icu_55::BreakIterator::getRuleStatus() const'
ext/intl/breakiterator/.libs/codepointiterator_internal.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3PHP22CodePointBreakIteratorE[_ZTVN3PHP22CodePointBreakIteratorE]+0xb0): undefined reference to `icu_55::BreakIterator::getRuleStatusVec(int*, int, UErrorCode&)'
ext/intl/idn/.libs/idn.o: In function `php_intl_idn_to':
/tmp/kitchen/cache/php-5.6.20/ext/intl/idn/idn.c:233: undefined reference to `uidna_IDNToASCII_55'
/tmp/kitchen/cache/php-5.6.20/ext/intl/idn/idn.c:235: undefined reference to `uidna_IDNToUnicode_55'
ext/intl/idn/.libs/idn.o: In function `php_intl_idn_to_46':
/tmp/kitchen/cache/php-5.6.20/ext/intl/idn/idn.c:147: undefined reference to `uidna_openUTS46_55'
/tmp/kitchen/cache/php-5.6.20/ext/intl/idn/idn.c:155: undefined reference to `uidna_nameToASCII_UTF8_55'
/tmp/kitchen/cache/php-5.6.20/ext/intl/idn/idn.c:200: undefined reference to `uidna_close_55'
/tmp/kitchen/cache/php-5.6.20/ext/intl/idn/idn.c:158: undefined reference to `uidna_nameToUnicodeUTF8_55'
/tmp/kitchen/cache/php-5.6.20/ext/intl/idn/idn.c:163: undefined reference to `uidna_close_55'
ext/intl/spoofchecker/.libs/spoofchecker_class.o: In function `spoofchecker_clone_obj':
/tmp/kitchen/cache/php-5.6.20/ext/intl/spoofchecker/spoofchecker_class.c:135: undefined reference to `uspoof_clone_55'
ext/intl/spoofchecker/.libs/spoofchecker_class.o: In function `spoofchecker_object_destroy':
/tmp/kitchen/cache/php-5.6.20/ext/intl/spoofchecker/spoofchecker_class.c:195: undefined reference to `uspoof_close_55'
ext/intl/spoofchecker/.libs/spoofchecker_create.o: In function `zim_Spoofchecker___construct':
/tmp/kitchen/cache/php-5.6.20/ext/intl/spoofchecker/spoofchecker_create.c:40: undefined reference to `uspoof_open_55'
/tmp/kitchen/cache/php-5.6.20/ext/intl/spoofchecker/spoofchecker_create.c:47: undefined reference to `uspoof_getChecks_55'
/tmp/kitchen/cache/php-5.6.20/ext/intl/spoofchecker/spoofchecker_create.c:48: undefined reference to `uspoof_setChecks_55'
ext/intl/spoofchecker/.libs/spoofchecker_main.o: In function `zim_Spoofchecker_isSuspicious':
/tmp/kitchen/cache/php-5.6.20/ext/intl/spoofchecker/spoofchecker_main.c:41: undefined reference to `uspoof_checkUTF8_55'
/tmp/kitchen/cache/php-5.6.20/ext/intl/spoofchecker/spoofchecker_main.c:44: undefined reference to `u_errorName_55'
ext/intl/spoofchecker/.libs/spoofchecker_main.o: In function `zim_Spoofchecker_areConfusable':
/tmp/kitchen/cache/php-5.6.20/ext/intl/spoofchecker/spoofchecker_main.c:74: undefined reference to `uspoof_areConfusableUTF8_55'
/tmp/kitchen/cache/php-5.6.20/ext/intl/spoofchecker/spoofchecker_main.c:77: undefined reference to `u_errorName_55'
ext/intl/spoofchecker/.libs/spoofchecker_main.o: In function `zim_Spoofchecker_setAllowedLocales':
/tmp/kitchen/cache/php-5.6.20/ext/intl/spoofchecker/spoofchecker_main.c:104: undefined reference to `uspoof_setAllowedLocales_55'
/tmp/kitchen/cache/php-5.6.20/ext/intl/spoofchecker/spoofchecker_main.c:107: undefined reference to `u_errorName_55'
ext/intl/spoofchecker/.libs/spoofchecker_main.o: In function `zim_Spoofchecker_setChecks':
/tmp/kitchen/cache/php-5.6.20/ext/intl/spoofchecker/spoofchecker_main.c:127: undefined reference to `uspoof_setChecks_55'
/tmp/kitchen/cache/php-5.6.20/ext/intl/spoofchecker/spoofchecker_main.c:130: undefined reference to `u_errorName_55'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sapi/cli/php] Error 1
```

Any help will be appreciated. List of packages installed before compile:

```
git wget libbz2-dev libgmp-dev re2c libvpx-dev libxslt-dev libtidy-dev libreadline6 libreadline6-dev libfreetype6-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libldap2-dev libjpeg-dev libjpeg62-dev libpng-dev libbz2-dev libicu-dev libaspell-dev libgd-dev libgmp3-dev php-mail-mime libmcrypt-dev libc-client2007e-dev openssl libssl-dev libxml2-dev libxpm-dev libhiredis-dev
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, looks like I hit a bug here.

I already had ICU installed from source on my machine and did mention it's path:

```
--with-icu-dir=/opt/icu4c
```

However, it was still picking up the package 'libicu-dev', which was causing the issue. It should have picked it up from the path I mentioned only, even if there was a package for that.

Nevertheless, uninstalled the 'libicu-dev' package and the installation is complete.